# Sql how to return multiple rows as one row

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to the SQL-world and I'm struggling with my result set...

I use 2 CTEs that I link together as

- CTE A: select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K (from 8 diff tables)
- CTE B: select A, B, C, D, E, L (from 6 diff tables; A through E are the same)

I then try to get a result table which does the following:

**A,B,C, 1st,2nd,3d**

-> A-D: the identifying columns which determine what specific item we're talking about

1st, 2nd and 3d depend on what values are found in the CTE

My query is as follows:

```
select A.A, A.B,A.C,A.D,
case
when EXISTS(select B.E from B join on A on xxx and B.E= 030) then  (select B.E from B join on A on xxx and B.E= 030)
else  A.H
end as "1st",
case
when EXISTS (select B.E from B join on A on xxx and B.E= 031) then B.E
when NOT EXISTS (select B.E from B join on A on xxx and B.E= 030) then A.K
else A.H
end as "2nd",
case
when EXISTS (select B.E from B join on A on xxx and B.E= 031) then A.H
else A.K
end as "3d"
from A
```

Extra info:

- B.E = 031 can not exist without B.E = 030
- in CTE-A G-K can be null; in CTE-B there exist no null-values
- if both B.E = 030 and B.E = 031 exist, then A.I,A.J and A.K are null

The problem in my result set:
I get

```
A | B | C | D | 1st | 2nd | 3d  |
a | b | c | d | x   | null| null|
a | b | c | d | null| y   | null|
a | b | c | d | null| null| z   |
```

I would like to have those results for the same A-D on the row.
GROUP BY does not work since I don't have an aggregate function.
If I were to include A.E as well, I'd see a different value for each row eg:

```
A | B | C | D | E  |  1st | 2nd | 3d |
a | b | c | d | 030| x   | null| null|
a | b | c | d | 031| null| y   | null|
a | b | c | d | 100| null| null| z   |
```

Any ideas on how to get this to return on a single row?

**EDIT**:

- why 2 CTE's: I've written and rewritten this query lots of times and ended up with this as a result.
  I tried subquery with different layers, 1 CTE, and different types of joins (left, inner) but it all gives the same result as this.
- I tried GROUP BY as this is the only way I know to aggregate rows

CTE A returns:

```
ITEM    | NAME   | SUB   | SUB2    | NR | F  | G    | H     | I  | J    | K
ItemA  |testname | 0101  |sub2test | 100|GRa |GR    | val1  | GRb| GR   | Val2
ItemB  |testname2| Z101  |sub2test2| 100|FRa |FR    | val3  |null| null | null
ItemC  |testname3| D401  |sub2test3| 100|Daa |Dx    | val5  |null| null | null
```

CTE B returns:

```
ITEM    | NAME    | SUB   | SUB2         | NR   | L
ItemB   |testname2| Z101  |sub2test2     | 30   | textL
ItemB   |testname2| Z101  |sub2test2     | 31   | textK
```

In result, this will give

```
ITEM   | NAME     | SUB    |SUB2     | 1st | 2nd | 3d
ItemA  |testname  | 0101   |sub2test |val1 | val2| null
ItemB  |testname2 | Z101   |sub2test2|textL|null | null
ItemB  |testname2 | Z101   |sub2test2|null |textK|val3
ItemC  |testname3 | D401   |sub2test3|val5 |null | null
```

for ItemB I want it on 1 single row

Comment: this is extremely confusing... here I am kindly asking for some edit, please use different name between table and column name, at least name table like: tbA, tbB or name column like: colA, colB.

Comment: Which database do you use? SQL is a language, TOAD is a tool.

Comment: Your question is completely unclear. Please, provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). *GROUP BY does not work since I don't have an aggregate function* - of course DBMS will not aggregate for you until you explicitly add some aggregation. But why you do not have it?

Comment: I'm lost at what the two CTEs are for.  The question specifically says:  "we're talking about 1st,2nd and 3d depend on what values are found in the CTE".  That I would get.  One CTE, but what do two have to do with the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using `GROUP BY` and `LISTAGG`?

Something along the lines of

```
SELECT 
    ITEM, NAME, SUB, SUB2,
    LISTAGG(1ST) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1ST) AS 1ST,
    LISTAGG(2ND) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 2ND) AS 2ND,
    LISTAGG(3RD) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 3RD) AS 3RD
FROM yourCteResult
GROUP BY ITEM, NAME, SUB, SUB2
```